# Uneven performances between EF Core and SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ssms

I'm running a parametrized 'SELECT' query using EF Core over a large SQL Server database.
When running the exact same query (with the same parameter values) from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I observe very uneven performances result.

In the most extreme cases (depending on the values of the parameters), the performance is improved by a magnitude of 2000 when executed from SSMS.
For instance, the query can take 10ms when executed from SSMS, and 20 seconds from EF Core.

- I'm capturing the query generated by EF Core using SQL Server Profiler, the text is copied without any change to SSMS.
- The performances are also measured from SQL Server Profiler.
- The query has a 'TOP 10' clause so that the volume of data returned cannot affect the performances.

My guess is that SQL Server is not using the same query plan in both cases.

- What could explain such a discrepancy?
- Are there some connection options that could influence the way the query plan is selected?
- What could I do to investigate that issue more in depth?

Comment: I would suggest you to start from this article https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Aside from the typical `@@options` differences SSMS also has numerous speed advantages because it doesn't download all of the data in LOB/max fields. Go to Tools > Options > Query Results, bump the Results to Grid and Results to Text values to their maximum settings, close and reopen your query tabs and try again.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this can be caused by parameter sniffing. If that is the cause, there some techniques to avoid bad query plans being cached. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the very valuable comments from @Sergey et @RossBush, I have been able to find the reason for that behavior:

- The queries executed from EF Core and from SSMS were not considered as identical by SQL Server because of differences in the formatting of the SQL (additional spaces). Each query had its own query plan.
- The parameter values provided on the first run of the query are used to compute the query plan. These values were not the same in both cases, which led to very different results.

After clearing the cache using `dbcc freesystemcache('MyDbName')` and running the query from both sides with the same parameter values, I now have the exact same execution time.

That issue beeing cleared, I have been able to adjust the indexes to improve the overall performances.